# Python / Excel / VBA / Macro - Error message running multiple macros

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have a very strange and I tried a couple of days to solve it but I haven't managed and was wondering if someone could help me.
I want to sequentially run a macro that is within multiple excel files i.e. excel 1 and 2 both have macro a and b.

```
wb = xw.Book("excel1.xlsb", update_links=False)
wb.macro("macro1")()
wb.macro("macro2")()
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

The first run after booting the computer this works without any problem both macro1 and two are executed.
When I then open excel2 file I get an error message with the second macro

```
wb = xw.Book("excel2.xlsb", update_links=False)
wb.macro("macro1")()
wb.macro("macro2")()
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

**in excel:**

Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

**in jupyter:**

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146788248), None)

However, if I split the code and run

```
wb = xw.Book("excel2.xlsb", update_links=False)
wb.macro("macro1")()
```

and I click into the excel with my cursor so that Excel is activated and I go back to jupyter notebook and execute

```
wb.macro("macro2")()
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

then it works and I don't get this error message. In general, that seems very odd to me and I tried to replicate what I manually do in the code by activating the wb with seal_focus=True

```
wb = xw.Book("excel2.xlsb", update_links=False)
wb.macro("macro1")()
wb.activate(steal_focus=True)
time.sleep(5)
wb.macro("macro2")()
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

But I get the same error message. The macros are in modules.
And if I split the code again i.e. I first run

```
wb = xw.Book("excel2.xlsb", update_links=False)
wb.macro("macro1")()
```

and then:

```
wb.activate(steal_focus=True)
wb.macro("macro2")()
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

The first time I execute the second part I get the same error message. However if I execute the second part a second time then it works. But this is not a solution for me as it should run in one go. I can't seem to understand nor find a solution for this. Anyone out there with a potential solution? Am I missing anything?

Many thanks

Tom

Comment: Seems like the problem is how your VBA is written, but we can't see it so...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the VBA code. I basically have to design the python code around to get it to work. I find a work around but it is not very elegant:
        wb.activate(steal_focus=True)
        app.calculate()
        time.sleep(2)
        keyboard.press(Key.up)
        time.sleep(2)
        app.calculate()